# Unable to Estimate Gas When Calling withdraw Function in Solidity Contract on Polygon Network

Tags: solidity, metamask

I've deployed a Solidity smart contract on the Polygon network, which includes a `withdraw` function. The contract code is based on Solidity version `0.8.16` and leverages the `OpenZeppelin` library for reentrancy guards and ECDSA cryptography. Below is the contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.16;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/security/ReentrancyGuardUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/ECDSA.sol";

contract PandaByteNew is ReentrancyGuardUpgradeable
{
    address private owner;
    address private signer;
    mapping(bytes32 => bool) private processedMessages;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    event Withdrawal(
        address  user,
        address  token,
        uint256 amount
    );

    modifier isOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Caller is not owner");
        _;
    }

    function changeSigner(address _newSigner) public isOwner (){
        signer = _newSigner;
    }

    function withdraw(
        address tokenAddress, 
        uint amount, 
        string memory transactionId, 
        bytes calldata signature
    ) external nonReentrant {
        string memory message = string.concat(
            transactionId,
            Strings.toString(amount)
        );

        require(!processedMessages[keccak256(abi.encodePacked(message))], "Message already processed");
        require(IERC20(tokenAddress).balanceOf(address(this)) >= amount, "Not enough balance, please contact PandaByte");
        require(verifyMessage(message, signature));
        IERC20(tokenAddress).transfer(msg.sender, amount);
        processedMessages[keccak256(abi.encodePacked(message))]=true;

        emit Withdrawal(msg.sender, tokenAddress, amount);
    }

    function verifyMessage(
        string memory message,
        bytes calldata signature
    ) public view returns  (bool) {
        return ECDSA.recover(
                ECDSA.toEthSignedMessageHash(
                    keccak256(abi.encodePacked(message))
                ),
                signature
            ) == signer;
    }

    function eth_sign_prefix_hash(bytes32 messageHash) internal pure returns (bytes32) {
        return keccak256(abi.encodePacked("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32", messageHash));
    }
}
```

The contract is deployed at this address: [PolygonScan](https://polygonscan.com/address/0xf880aEFda174c2D45f46e2c17763e7574E93a340)

While testing the withdraw function via MetaMask, I encounter the following error message in the MetaMask popup:

```
We were not able to estimate gas. There might be an error in the contract and this transaction may fail.
```

Notably, when I test the contract in Remix, all functions work as expected without any issues.

Has anyone encountered this type of issue before? What could be the underlying problem and how can I resolve it?

Comment: can you provide the input parameters you're using to call the withdraw function?

Answer (score 0):

Failure to estimate gas isn't a cause it's a symptom, if you get that it just means the transaction will not succeed so you need to debug the cause of the failure.

Looks like inputs are:

```
tokenAddress: 0xc2132D05D31c914a87C6611C10748AEb04B58e8F
amount: 10000
transactionId: 20230915190902AMRHWBV
signature: 0x2c530071210a182f740e4eadca2763a8d9909ecde52a333e7af2493e4e5d3b37609195100134d08b656ada01ef79db99ffc5959420120aa07962b697b83149ce1b
```

Transaction is failing at the first require

```js
require(!processedMessages[keccak256(abi.encodePacked(message))], "Message already processed");
```

There's a non reentrant check, toString is called on amount, then fails at require.

If I change a part of the message it fails at the `verifyMessage`

Don't want to debug further, but you can step through it fairly easily with tool like https://tenderly.co